# Name convention error with write to file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm running into a problem with the following code and writing an excel file name. This code is driven by user defined inputs for location and chemical compound desired. The desired output is a file with the chemical compound and location appended for the name. The problem is that any compound with a . in it errors out. For example, if I want PM2.5 for site Kenny, the file name should be PM2.5 Kenny. The code however is recognizing ".5" as a file extension when this is to be part of the name. Any help how to get around this would be appreciated.

The error this gives is:
Unrecognized file extension '.5 Kenny'.  Use the 'FileType' parameter to specify the file type.

```
j = 1
i = 1
while j <= width(c_locations_of_interest)
    while i <= width(c_data_types_of_interest)
        Value = c_data_types_of_interest{1,i}
        Location = c_locations_of_interest{1,j}
        output_excel_file = append(Value,' ',Location)        
        
        STATEMENTS    
        
        writetable(T, output_excel_file)
    
        i = i + 1
    end
    i = 1
    j = j + 1
end
```

Comment: I added the error, the code is based off many examples but I'm uncertain how to handle this error.

It's treating the period in the name as starting a file extension, everything else for every other iteration runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem with a crude example. Indeed Matlab complains about file extensions. This is because I believe that you are missing the file extension, in your case '.xlsx'

Using `sprintf` instead of `Append`:

```
value = "PM2.5";
location = " Kenny"
extension = "xlsx";

output_excel_file= sprintf("%s%s.%s", value, location, extension);
writetable(T, output_excel_file);
```

Hope it is clear

EDIT: Corrected my own variables naming ¬¬

Comment: interest, what does the %s do?

Edit: I see it now. the %s is setting up the file structure. This code worked and gives me what I want. Thank you

Comment: %s is the formatting operator for character vector or string array. Please read the documentation for sprintf: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html EDIT: I must emphasize that my solution will also work with Append by addint the extension at the end. However, in my experience, sprintf is more reliable

Comment: I attempted adding the extension at the end but with the location being a random variable, it didn't like that. The sprintf is a better solution it appears.

Comment: Yes, I believe that Append is for single elements. Generally, I do not recommend using it for cases like yours. Always stick to robust functions.